# issue connecting to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, wiki.js

While installing **wiki.js** in the configure window, **wiki.js** is unable to connect to **mongodb** and **mongodb** is unable to start the service. Executing this command wont give any error:

```
systemctl start mongodb.service; 
systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

While, `systemctl start mongod` pops an error message saying:

> Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found

in the configure window it shows:

> Error: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
> [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Try reinstalling mongodb

Comment: What gives `systemctl status mongodb.service`? `mongod` is used to start the service. In order to connect to the service use the mongo shell `mongo`